# How to find document with some keys without duplicate value?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document `Keelung` that has an array `movie` with 6 object.

I want find the document `db.getCollection('Keelung').find({})` but without duplicate value in `enName`.

[image]

For instance, if there are two `enName` value is `Truth or Dare`, my query command will return 5 objects.

I have no idea how to achieve it, try `db.getCollection('Keelung').find({ enName : true, dropDups : true })` is not right obviously.

Is any way to achieve it in mongodb ? Or i should filter it in front end ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

According @Sergio suggest and i google find `$addToSe`

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$data' },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id', movie: { $addToSet: '$enName' } } }
]);
```

Nothing happened, i have no idea how to use find query in this command...

Comment: This can probably be done with aggregation pipeline and its `$group` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  aggregation here

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": '$movie' },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$movie.enName",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "field1": "$field1",
        "field2": "$field2",
        ...
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, it can filter. I will try to find out $group $push $unwind